# Book about a live reality tv show where money depends on viewers but they were really harvesting dreams

Tags: story-identification, books, dreams

There's a book I checked out of the library a couple years ago and I'd like to get my sister to read it but I don't remember what it's called.

I actually don't remember if you got money or not but I know the amount of viewers you had was important. There was a teenage girl from a poor city in Arizona I think. Her and a bunch of other kids went to a facility where they were constantly filmed. I remember she started to develop a relationship with a dishwasher there and that put her in the spotlight. There was a giant screen that showed everyone being filmed and you could see the amount of viewers watching you since they could tune in to whoever they wanted.

The book had a map at the beginning and started with her on top of a tower next to a spotlight.

But the **main** cool part of the book was that the producers were harvesting something from the children at night while they were asleep. I think it was dreams or something like that. They all slept in pods and they would gas the pod to make sure they were asleep before taking them away and bringing them back before morning. For some reason she had two minds where one would turn on when she was asleep so she saw her friend being taken away. She mentioned it was like a dolphin's brain. It ending with her in a trippy dream scene where while they were trying to harvest her dreams (maybe) she got away but her other brain was scared or something so she let her go and I clearly remember it ended with her becoming a disembodied smile.

And saw once that the sequel was about them lost and trying to find each other, but I never got a chance to read it. I think it was a trilogy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year is "a while back?"  Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: I mean like a couple years ago. I'll edit that.

Comment: As for the cover, I don't remember much, just that it had a white background.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Vault of Dreamers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20518838-the-vault-of-dreamers), book one of a trilogy by Caragh M. O'Brien.

[image: The Vault of Dreamers]

> Welcome to the prestigious Forge School of the Arts, where every waking moment of the students' lives is televised. For twelve hours a day, every class, conversation, and gesture is broadcast to millions of viewers. And for twelve hours each night, the students undergo an induced sleep, proven to maximize creativity.

The map you remember at the beginning of the book is the map of the school:

[image: Map]

The main protagonist is Rosie Sinclair, and the bit you remember about the dolphin brain is when she has been drugged and is being interrogated by the dean  of the school (Sandy Berg) and Dr. Ash:

> “She’s not lying, Sandy,” said Dr. Ash. “See for yourself. You’re tapped so deep, I doubt she’ll even remember this conversation when she comes around.”
>
> “She’ll remember it,” he said. “She’s conscious. She’s just sleeping, too.”
>
> “That isn’t possible,” Dr. Ash said.
>
> “Just look.”
>
> I’m like a dolphin with a double-duty brain, I thought, blinking my eyes open again. I wanted to laugh in despair and pain.

Comment: Yep! Thanks so much!